# How to save the values in an Eager Loaded class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading, edmx

To add a role into my user and save it:

```
var user = DataContext.Users
    .Include("Roles")
    .Where(u => u.UserName.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
    .FirstOrDefault();
foreach (string rolename in roleNames)
{
    var role = FindRoleByName(rolename);
    user.Roles.Add(role);
    DataContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; // probably not needed
    DataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it throws the exception

```
[System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException]   
{"Unable to update the EntitySet 'UserRoles' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation."} System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
```

What is the correct way to write this update?

------Update--------

If I remove the `<DefiningQuery>` section in the edmx model, the eager loading will fail at `.include("Roles")` part in the LINQ statement.

Also, I found some error comment in the edmx (in xml editor). I guess that is where the problem is. It says:

```
<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6002: The table/view 'DNR.dbo.UserRoles' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.
-->
```

So, do I have to add a primary key in the joining table along with my `UserId_FK` and `RoleId_FK`?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a mapping problem. It happens for example if the entities are mapped from a database view and/or the primary key is missing.

You can find a few possible solutions at the MSDN Forum: [Unable to update the EntitySet](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/220262bd-85d4-4f29-96a8-4a7d1d2c8293/)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like pointing to the right direction. But simply removing the `<DefiningQuery>` causes breakup of all eager loading. I am looking at more articles on this topic.

Comment: In the backend database, the joining table contains `UserId_FK`, `RoleId_FK`. Is it required to have a primary key like `UserRoleId_PK`?

Comment: @Blaise: No, you don't need a separate PK column. Just define a composite PK consisting of `UserId_FK` **and** `RoleId_FK`. (In SSMS click the PK button twice - once for each column.)